# Sorting an Arraylist with graphic and user input

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, alphabetical

I'm having some trouble trying to sort an `ArrayList` from A-Z and Z-A.

This is my Arraylist:

```
ArrayList<String> ordlista = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is how the user input words into my array list:

```
ordlista.add(txtOrd.getText());
```

If it's possible I would also prefer it to not be stricted to capital letters when sorting.

I'm using graphic and I want the sorted list to be printed in a textarea called `txtOutput`

Comment: what language do you use? java, c#, ..?

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd Very very clear that it's Java, also it's tagged.

Comment: @MarounMaroun sorry it was I who tagged it with 'java' -) Now I'm start thinking if I made a mistake or not

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd Oh.. sorry I didn't notice that, yes it's Java you didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Edit Your Question Proper way

Comment: I'm sorry for not making the best question, first time posting here and I only did what I was told

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.sort` on your `List` to sort the `String`s by default order, that is, lexicographic order.

Use `Collections.reverse` to reverse your `List`.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> ordlista = new ArrayList<>();
ordlista.add("z");
ordlista.add("a");
ordlista.add("b");
// printing (not sorted)
System.out.println(ordlista);
// sorting
Collections.sort(ordlista);
// printing (sorted)
System.out.println(ordlista);
// reversing
Collections.reverse(ordlista);
// printing (reversed)
System.out.println(ordlista);
```

**Output**

```
[z, a, b]
[a, b, z]
[z, b, a]
```

Comment: I'm using graphic so I need to print it in a textfield named txtOutput. Because right now its printing in system. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @user3492980 that's out of scope for your present question, I suggest you ask a new one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use collections to sort arraylist:

```
Collections.sort(ordlista);
```